# Which counter generates timer interrupts?

Tags: linux, time, real-time, interrupt

I did a `iotop` to observe the interrupts on my computer. This is the interrupt shown most often.

```
  0 [PIC-edge      time]   247 Ints/s     (max:   389)
```

I believe it's the `timer interrupt`, well since it's named time and is numbered 0.

Where are the timer interrupt signals generated from? Are they triggered after a certain amount of processor ticks passed, or by some external counter?

---

The `Ints/s` vary by amount of +-30. Shouldn't the frequency be stable?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567214/what-are-linux-local-timer-interrupts, specifically this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10567417/33204. It appears to have what you're looking for.